# How to get a binary tree for all generations

Tags: mysql, sql, binary-tree

I have a database table structured as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Binary_Tree(
node_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
parent_node_id VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL CHECK (parent_node_id <> node_id),
node_flag CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'L' NOT NULL CHECK (node_flag IN ('L', 'R')),
username VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT NULL,
createdAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updatedAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

- node_id is the id of the user (generated ids, eg, 937-G3876D)
- parent_node_id is the id of the parent to this child (generated ids eg, -655R3876D)
- node_flag: is the position in which this user is placed in the tree (L & R).

I'm using Node js and Express for my server and using MYSQL npm dependency.
Each parent will have a max of two children, i.e LEFT and RIGHT.

here is a screen of the Binary_Tree table

[image]

**MY CHALLENGE:**

1. I want to get a binary tree of all generations for each parent_node_id

I'll be gladened for any assistant.

Comment: What type of SQL? Some falvours of SQL offer a graph api, which is what would help you here

Comment: Do you want achieve it with SQL? Which programming language are you using? It seems to be mysql, is that right?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  I'm using MSQL , but I would love to try any other better option.

Comment: @btafarelo, Actually, I tried neo4j and couldn't get my way around it, so I optioned in for MYSQL I'm currently using express for my server. And it's MSQL I'm using.

Comment: SQL is not the ideal language for this. Use a programming language with more possibilities. Can you add example input in text format (not image) and the corresponding desired output? Also: limit your question to just one question otherwise it will be considered too broad and votes for closure will come in.

Comment: Please @Nick.McDermaid, any solution or guide?

Comment: Please @btafarelo any solution or guide?

Comment: @OmegaUwedia your question isn't clear for me. How would you achieve it? Programming language... In SQL it "can be done" for each row of parent_id get two columns, using subqueries what would make it slow. Do you have only two children for each parent? Many questions...

Comment: @btafarelo, I'm using node js and express for server, I'm using MySQL .  Do you have only two children for each parent? YES, Left AND Right